# How to fade in and out color of svg

Tags: css, animation, svg

I want an svg object to fade from color 'A' to color 'B' then back to color 'A' indefinitely.

Thus far I have had limited success using

```
<animate attributeName="fill" from="colorA" to="colorB" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

But this doesn't allow me to fade back to color 'A'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `values` attribute instead of `from` and `to`.

```html
<svg>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%">
    <animate attributeName="fill" values="red;blue;red" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use a custom css animation to achieve this:

```
@keyframes colorChange {
    0%{fill:#ff0000}
    50%{fill:#000}
    100%{fill: #ff0000}
}
.box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    animation: colorChange 3s infinite;
}
```

Just apply the `animation` property to whatever element you want to have the fill change
http://jsfiddle.net/re8tn1o3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply will have to try this too. Good opportunity for me to learn about keyframes in css animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can affect color of SVG with its "path" attribute. Example from SCSS:

```
.container {
    svg {
        path {
            animation: colorChange 3s infinite;
        }
    }
}
@keyframes colorChange {
    0%{fill:#ffffff}
    50%{fill:#000000}
    100%{fill: #ffffff}
}
```